# How can I exit a Sudoku solver function if the puzzle is unsolvable?

Tags: python, recursion

The below solve takes a Sudoku board and solves it. if an unsolvable board is given as input it runs on for ever. how to exit unsolvable case?

```
try:
   solve(board)
except:
    print('unsolvable')
```

this is what I tried.

is_empty() checks and returns a tuple of i,j.

```
def solve(board):
    pos = is_empty(board)
    if not(pos):
        return True
    else:
        x , y = pos
    for i in range(1,10):
        if check(board,i,(x,y)):
            board[x][y]=i
            if solve(board):
                return True
            board[x][y]=0
    return False
```

a timeout error does not show at the end. Why is that?

Comment: What are the contents of check()?

Comment: check(board,number,position): loop number(1-9),#check row,#check column,#check 3x3cube

Comment: Those are the parameters, not the contents of the function itself. Anyway, I see that you call 'if solve(board)' inside of solve(board), so it infinitely calls itself without an exit condition.

Comment: yeah thats why i want a timeout error. but the function is not raising any.

Comment: A timeout won't solve anything, the first call of solve() will call solve() 10 times, and each one of those solve() will call solve 10 times for a total of 100 times, etc.